# Why is my database name truncated?

Tags: mariadb

I'm using MariaDB v5.x and want to return a long database's name with the query. I can successfully do this with a simple query, but with a more involved query the database name comes back truncated [34 characters]. Why does this happen and is there a way to retrieve the full, un-truncated name?

This example query works:

```
SELECT DATABASE() as 'database', hour as 'hour'
FROM time
WHERE hour = 1;
```

However, this type of query returns the truncated database name:

```
SELECT DATABASE() as 'database',
       t.hour as 'hour',
       d.day as 'day'
FROM   time t,
       day d
WHERE  t.day_pk = day.pk AND
       t.hour   = 1      AND
       d.day    = 22
UNION ALL
SELECT DATABASE() as 'database',
       t.hour as 'hour',
       d.day as 'day'
FROM   time t,
       day d
WHERE  t.day_pk = day.pk AND
       t.hour   = 1      AND
       d.day    = 24;
```

Thanks for any /all help.

D.

Comment: "MariaDB 5.x"? The unsupported one? And what is "x" in this case? They tend to introduce some major changes even in minor releases.

Comment: Please show us the actual input and output.  The characters involved may be a clue as to what went wrong.

Comment: It may help to use a `CAST(...)` on at least the first Select.

Comment: I assume you are using UNION to demonstrate the problem, if not you can use `d.day in (22,24)`. FWIW, I would avoid identifiers like time and day since they are reserved words (and no I would not use quotes to get around that problem). You may also want to have a look at ANSI joins instead of ",". In the long run I find it easier to maintain my code with these.

Comment: For @Lennart, the SQL is representative of the actual query, but good points regarding using `time` and `day`. As for using ASNI joins ... this format is, for me, the easiest to read and use when trying to tie a dozen tables together. Finally, since I'm not an SQL guru, any example of the `d.day in (22,24)` would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that the same behaviour is present even in MariaDB 10.7.1.

The truncation appears to happen when `UNION` is used.

Here is a workaround - use the `substring` function to indicate you want the full length:

```
SELECT substring(database() FROM 1 FOR length(database())) AS "database"
UNION ALL
SELECT substring(database() FROM 1 FOR length(database()));
```

Comment: This worked really well, @dbdemon, thank you. I understand what you did, taking the entire database name as a sub-string. This is not something I would have thought to do.

Comment: For @dbdemon, is the `FROM 1` related to the answer from @danblack where the results show `Field   1:  'database'`?

Comment: Its part of the [substring](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/substring/) syntax that coerces the length of the field. `UNION ALL` leaves the type determination to the first query, but for currently unknown reasons this is different to the single query on its own.

Comment: For @danblack, it was the `... FOR length(database()` that threw me. I was looking at FOR loops instead of the substring page. Thanks for pointing to the correct syntax.

Comment: [Fixed in 10.2.42+, 10.3.33+, 10.4.23+, 10.5.14+, 10.6.6+, 10.7.2+ and 10.8.0+](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/1d27b5789aaa353175f5331d3a8b104b22dd1fce)

Answer (score 2):

Confirming what @dbdemon posted this is a bug that is also present in all versions. Using `--column-type-info` shows a little more insight as to what's happening.

```
$ db=$(printf 'a%.0s' {1..40})
$ echo $db
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
$ podman run -d --rm -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=$db -e MYSQL_USER=u -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=p --name m55 mariadb:5.5
1b2c0740bf664b8a3da8071bb96234a86fe8dd5f3eb6348598f5d0c2b59ede56

$ podman exec -ti m55 mysql -u u -pp  --column-type-info -e 'select database() as "database" union all select database()' $db
Field   1:  `database`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       VAR_STRING
Collation:  latin1_swedish_ci (8)
Length:     34
Max_length: 34
Decimals:   0
Flags:      


+------------------------------------+
| database                           |
+------------------------------------+
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa |
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa |
+------------------------------------+

$ podman exec -ti m55 mysql -u u -pp  --column-type-info -e 'select database()' $db
Field   1:  `database()`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       VAR_STRING
Collation:  latin1_swedish_ci (8)
Length:     34
Max_length: 40
Decimals:   31
Flags:      


+------------------------------------------+
| database()                               |
+------------------------------------------+
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa |
+------------------------------------------+
```

[From the code](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.2/sql/item_strfunc.h#L720) we can see the 34 comes from the [MAX_FIELD_NAME](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.2/sql/sql_const.h#L32) rather than the [64 NAME_CHAR_LEN](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.2/include/mysql_com.h#L30) from various definitions of `Db` in system tables.

These sorts of bugs are easy to fix. Please [report them](https://jira.mariadb.org) (whether easy or not).

Update: [Bug MDEV-27544 created](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27544)

Update: Fixed in 10.2.42+, 10.3.33+, 10.4.23+, 10.5.14+, 10.6.6+, 10.7.2+ and 10.8.0+

Comment: While a bit above my database knowledge, this information is quite interesting, thank you.

Comment: It was a fun investigation, and just showing that MariaDB is just code and things happen for a reason. I've lodged [MDEV-27544](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27544) as a bug report but the level of detail in your original question was enough to do a bug report. The currently minimum developed version is 10.2, so while you are on 5.5 you'll have to survive with @dbdemon's workarounds. By the time you upgrade it should be fixed.

Comment: For @danblack, the bug report is most awesome, thank you. Unfortunately, my legacy system will be stuck on v5.5 for quite some time, but when we eventually get to v10 there will lots of new tricks to take advantage of, this being one.

Comment: Well its fixed now. Not really a trick, just something that should of been fixed a while ago (if anyone noticed). Happy to have any feedback of what would make an upgrade easier (probably off the channel, should be able to find my email easy enough).